# How to draw this line with bezierpath

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion

Maybe someone knows how to draw this type of line with bezierpath?

[image]

Comment: What have your tried so far and what errors have your come across?

Comment: I can draw line without blur (not soft line). I don't know how to do that type of line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [NSShadow](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSShadow_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to setup a blur around your path. Use 0 as X and Y offsets, and set a large blur before drawing the path.

Answer (score 1):

Use +bezierPathWithRoundedRect:xRadius:yRadius: to make the "pill" shape. Set your shadow (as Laurent Etiemble suggested) and your drawing color and -fill the path. It'll be solid black with a shadow.